# How do I access remote machine that runs on Pow (rails web server)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rack-pow

I've recently installed Pow on my Mac. It's great.

It's convenient for my own dev machine. But I wonder if I can set it up to be shared by my colleagues. The problem is DNS resolution part.

For example, if I have a dev site on my machine like "http://myapp.dev". How do I let my colleague access to the site on my machine from his machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hacky way to do this is to make them edit their DNS and insert a record in `/etc/hosts` that maps to your machine. An easier way to do this is [Localghost](http://scotchi.net/localghost/) which doesn't require editing files by hand.

Comment: Strange I tried this. All my devices are connected via wifi. But don't connect. any ideas?

Comment: @Trip You can always test this in principle with `curl -HHost:hostname ip` where `hostname` is your dev site name like `test.dev`, and `ip` is your IP address like `192.168.1.10`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using https://showoff.io and it works a treat. Also allows others not on local network to view it as well (if that's something you need).